# Bluetooth not running on my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I tried to solve my problem with previous question that already asked but they don't work for me.
I want to run my Bluetooth driver for connecting to other devices but my Bluetooth ,that I run from Unity Control Center, have disabled buttons.
My `rfkill list` is as below:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am in HP Probook G0 450

Comment: Do you have the `bluez*` packages installed?

Comment: I didn't have that, I install it

Comment: I install it but that doesn't work still, I read a forum in Hp Help Center and they don't support Linux drivers

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb` command?

Comment: `lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:0359 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: `Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 24ae:6600  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
`

Comment: I guess it's the driver matter, try a newer version of ubuntu(18.04 live is recommended).

Comment: Yes It is because of Bluetooth driver that i already mentioned, Thanks